# How to print BeautifulSoup object in a compact form as when pressing F12 in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, python-3.x, google-chrome, beautifulsoup

I've found that the view of Google Chrome when pressing F12 is compact and convenient when inspecting an html. Take this [url](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/pomme) as an example, it returns the html with tags collapsed

[image]

I would like to ask if we can print an html in this compact form in python. Thank you so much!

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/aimer', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `prettify()` function:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: but it expands all the entry :(

Comment: I don't think that there is any way to keep HTML tags collapsed (

Answer (score 0):

Try this to do [Non-pretty printing](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=prettify#non-pretty-printing):

```py
print(str(soup))
```

This is a compact form, but not a collapse.